# Single Collection vs Multiple collections with same fields in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection in `mongodb` by the name `Order`. It has many fields some of which are mentioned below:

**Order**

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Hello1",
    "orderType": "Type1",
    "date": "2016-09-23T15:07:38.000Z"
     ...... //11 more fields
}
```

In the above `collection`, I have mentioned only 4 fields but in actual collection, I have around 15 fields. `Order` can be of 2 types: `Type1` or `Type2`. It is mentioned in `orderType` field.

Now, for the `Type2` order, I have all the `15` fields but it also have additional 5-7 fields. I have a single `Order` collection and I was wondering should I create `2` different collections for each type of orders; or whether I could keep this collection only and add additional fields here only. I have already written most of the logic considering only 1 collection Will it be worth the effort making it 2 different collections? If I keep a single collection, am I losing anything in terms of performance?

Comment: Do it the way you want, it depends on your need, but there's no problem at all with having different kind of documents in the same collection, and it may even be easier this way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keeping data on `single collection` is usually better in terms of performance since you can get required data mostly in a single query.

Since from the question I can mostly think it is a [one-to-one relationship](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-embedded-one-to-one-relationships-between-documents/), embedded documents would be beneficial. Secondly, you are yourself saying that you have already written most of the logic considering only one collection then you should go forward with one collection only. Unless you have [one-to-many relationships](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-referenced-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/).

I would recommend you to go through [Data Model Design](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/data-model-design/) and understand when and which model is better.

Answer (score 4):

Embedded document would be best as you have one-to-one relationship.  For more info please check [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/data-model-design/).